# How can I sort the lists in the list?

Tags: python, list, sorting

I'd like to know how to sort the lists in the list. However, I don't want to align by key. I'd like to change it according to the following method.

```
arr = [[2, 3], [5, 1], [4, 1], [5, 3], [4, 2]]
# solution...
I_want_arr = [[2, 3], [1, 5], [1, 4], [3, 5], [2, 4]]
```

i tried it

```
for i in arr:
  i.sort()
```

but, it didn't work

Comment: Works for me [TM].

Comment: Your method works (assuming that you meant `arr` and not `graph`).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

using list comprehenstion:

```
arr = [[2, 3], [5, 1], [4, 1], [5, 3], [4, 2]]
sorted_output = [sorted(l) for l in arr]
```

using `map()`:

```
sorted_output = list(map(sorted, arr))
```

Answer (score 2):

**@Gabip's solution includes this and a more time efficient one, check that out first!**

How about

```py
arr = [[2, 3], [5, 1], [4, 1], [5, 3], [4, 2]]

I_want_arr = [sorted(x) for x in arr]
```

This outputs

```
[[2, 3], [1, 5], [1, 4], [3, 5], [2, 4]]
```